# XPath: Retrieve all ancestors of current node but stop when find specific node

Tags: php, xpath

XML example:

```
<node-root>
  <node-1>
   <node-2>
     ....
     <node-1000>
       <node-1001>
         <node-1002>
          text
         </node-1002>
       </node-1001>
     </node-1000>
     ....
   </node-2>
  </node-1>
</node-root>
```

What I want is to retrieve all ancestors of the text node until `<node-1000>`.
My XPath query (PHP):

`$parentNodes = $xpath->query("ancestor::*" , $textNode);`

`$textNode` is the text node, which contains `text`. In PHP this means that query is executed from this node.
Obviously, this expression tries to find ALL ancestors, but this can lead to unnecessary resource consumption. In my case, I don't want to search parent nodes deeper than `<node-1000>`.  Is there the way to stop the query execution after `<node-1000>`. 
It's assumed that I don't know how many steps I should perform until would meet `<node-1000>`. So this can't be used: `../`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
$parentNodes = $xpath->query("ancestor::*[node-1000]/*" , $textNode);
```

This will give you the `<node-1000>` element, or

```
$parentNodes = $xpath->query("ancestor::*[node-1000]//*" , $textNode);
```

(with //*) which will fetch all of the nodes up to `<node-1000>`.

Edit: test code...

```
$data = <<< XML
<node-root>
  <node-1>
   <node-2>
     ....
     <node-1000>
       <node-1001>
         <node-1002>
         text
         </node-1002>
       </node-1001>
     </node-1000>
     ....
   </node-2>
  </node-1>
  <node-1>
   <node-2>
     ....
     <node-1000>
       <node-a></node-a>
       <node-c></node-c>
       <node-100>
       <n></n>
         <node-1002>
          text2
         </node-1002>
       </node-100>
     </node-1000>
     ....
   </node-2>
  </node-1></node-root>
XML;
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($data);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
// Next line - use item(0) to pick first, 1 for second
$textNode = $xpath->query("//node-1002")->item(1)->childNodes[0];
echo $xml->saveXML($textNode);
$parentNodes = $xpath->query("ancestor::*[node-1000]//*" , $textNode);
echo count($parentNodes).PHP_EOL;
echo $xml->saveXML($parentNodes->item(0));
```

With the second item this outputs...

```
          text2
         1
<node-1000>
       <node-a/>
       <node-c/>
       <node-100>
       <n/>
         <node-1002>
          text2
         </node-1002>
       </node-100>
     </node-1000>
```

Comment: Almost there. But the problem is that in this case, PHP ignores that context node (`$textNode`) is a starting point.

Comment: I've added my test code, which seems to give the right answer, where am I going wrong,

Comment: Technically in this particular case, your answer is right. So I will accept it. The problem arises when we have big XML document with lots of `node-1000` tags. This query will find ascendence not only from context node.

Comment: The expression works ONLY with this improbable source document where all the ancestors have exactly one child.

Comment: @MichaelKay I've updated the example and it seems to work with ancestors with multiple child elements, would be grateful if you could point out where this should be going wrong and how to do it properly.

Comment: The expression `ancestor::*[node-1000]//*` first finds all ancestors that have node-1000 as a child, and then finds all descendants of those ancestors, whether or not they are ancestors of the starting node.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I didn't see this in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

An XPath expression to select all nodes above or equal to `node-1000` is

```
ancestor::*[substring-after(local-name(),'node-')>=1000]
```

In PHP this would look like

```
$parentNodes = $xpath->query("ancestor::*[substring-after(local-name(),'node-')>=1000]" , $textNode);
```

If the currently selected node `$xpath` is `node-1002` this would select `node-1001` and `node-1000`.

Comment: This expression works ONLY if the node-names have the particular form in this example source document.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case (without assuming particular properties of your example), let's state the problem as follows: find all the ancestors of the context node up to (and including) the first node named X, where X is statically known; we'll assume that we don't care what happens if there is no ancestor named X.

You're using the default XPath processor in PHP so you're probably looking for an XPath 1.0 solution.

The best you can do in XPath 1.0 is probably

```
ancestor::*[ancestor-or-self::X]
```

but it's likely to be quite inefficient in a deep tree, because for each ancestor, you are searching all its ancestors.

So I would probably handle the logic from the host language, and make repeated calls to get the parent of the current node, stopping the search when X is found.

In XPath 3.1 you could do

```
let $X := ancestor-or-self::X[1] 
return ancestor::*[. >> $X]
```

But that's still less efficient than finding the parent repeatedly until a condition is satisfied.

Sadly, even in XPath 3.1, we don't have an "until" operator: `ancestor::* until self::X`. I've always thought this would be useful but never managed to drum up enough support for it. (One complication is that you really need both "until X inclusive" and "until X exclusive" variants.)

What we do have in XPath 3.1 is the ability to implement this operator yourself as a higher-order function:

```
let $until-inclusive := function($this, $next, $condition) {
    if (exists($this))
    then ($this, if ($condition($this)) then () else $next($this))
    else ()}
return $until-inclusive(., function($p){$p/..}, function($q){$q[self::X]})
```

If you're using an XPath 3.1 processor with support for higher-order functions (Saxon-PE is available from PHP...) then this is probably the best way of doing it in XPath - but it's still probably easier to do it in the host language.

Comment: Almost forgot. Thanks for the reply, I have really found that the easiest way was to implement a recursive function in the host language.Also thanks for letting me know about Saxon PHP API.